# SSH forwarded through modem recently started failing: update

Tags: openssh, port-forwarding

```
Server host Ubuntu 18.04: Openssh-server/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.1 amd64

Modem: Arris Xb6
```

Tested with clients:

- Ubuntu 18.10: openssh-client/cosmic,now 1:7.7p1-4 amd64
- Ubuntu 18.04: openssh-client/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.1 amd64
- Debian 9.5: openssh-client/stable,now 1:7.4p1-10+deb9u4 amd64

Until a recent firmware update, this modem was forwarding just fine. On the advice of my ISP tech support (modem provider), I reset the modem to factory to clean any residual bad cache and reconstructed the forwarding table.

No luck.

- The modem forwards to other ports just fine.
- The modem forwards telnet through to the host on the SSH port 22.

But attempting to create a SSH session fails.

The SSH server requires a key (passwords disabled) but behavior is same when forwarding to another SSH server listening on a different port. So this *seems to me* to be a SSH issue rather than an Arris issue but I'm keeping the Arris in the question because it could be relevant (I'm not a SSH or network wiz by any stretch!)

Three hosts (Behavior with Debian and the Ubuntus is the same)

1. `michigan` is the Arris hostname, forwarding to `acer` Ubuntu 18.04 host of the ssh server.
2. `vaio` is the Ubuntu 18.10 ssh client

`michigan` is set to forward to `acer`

I can ssh from vaio to acer, but I cannot ssh through michigan. Output for the connection attempts is pretty much the same except that the successful attempt to acer(the LAN hostname) includes all the following lines whereas the failed attempt to michigan (the modem hostname) has only the first of these lines:

```
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/stephen/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from acer
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/stephen/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from acer
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/stephen/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.0.0.110 (acer IP address)
```

The attempt to acer fails with the following:

```
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
Connection reset by <IP of acer> port 22
```

This happens even with firewalls off on modem and host.

DNS is through a LAN DNS but behavior is the same even if I request connect through the modem's IP address.

Searches for information about `SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY` have so far returned nothing useful.

Comment: Add another v ... `ssh -vv` should show debug2: messages for the remote connection...

Comment: @RubberStamp I have edited the question to include the output of vvv, plus a comment after looking more into the error message.