# SSH connection failure: processing of forwarded request fails on known_host key

Tags: openssh, port-forwarding

When I attempt a SSH connection between client C and server S (both on the same LAN) the client looks up the server's key in the client user's `known_hosts` file.

In the usual case for connection attempts, if the server's key is not found, the client is prompted to accept the server's key into the user's `known_hosts` file . If the key is found then the connection process continues.

However I have a situation where if the connection request is forwarded through the LAN router/modem the lookup for the server's key fails even though the target server's key ***is*** there, and the client is not prompted. Instead the attempt is refused with `Connection reset by <IP of router>`

Connect success to the LAN host directly using :

```
ssh -vvv stephen@acer
```

Connect failing to the LAN router to forward to acer using:

```
ssh -vvv stephen@michigan
```

This has just started happening. Any idea why?

- Is the server key altered by the router?
- Is the router replacing the target server's key with its own?
- Is there some way of getting a look at the key that's being passed. I am calling with `ssh -vvv` have the SSH logging set to `VERBOSE` but see nothing I recognize as useful

***System info:***

```
Server host Ubuntu 18.04: Openssh-server/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.1 amd64    
Tested with clients:  

- Ubuntu 18.10: openssh-client/cosmic,now 1:7.7p1-4 amd64  
- Ubuntu 18.04: openssh-client/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.1 amd64 
- Debian 9.5: openssh-client/stable,now 1:7.4p1-10+deb9u4 amd64

 Modem: Arris Xb6
```

Update to: [SSH forwarded through modem recently started failing: update](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483302/ssh-forwarded-through-modem-recently-started-failing-update)

Comment: What does the ssh command you are passing look like?

Comment: @MichaelProkopec I have added the commands to the question. Thank you.

Comment: You say forwarding to acer, are you saying that you are outside the LAN at that point.

Comment: @MichaelProkopec No For both those requests, I am inside the LAN on another host i.e. a host other than acer (hostname vaio). I don't think this is a loopback problem because I can access other services on acer in this way. SSH is the only service that has given me connection problems this far.

Comment: Check out rui's post: https://serverfault.com/questions/210408/ssh-access-problem-debug1-expecting-ssh2-msg-kex-dh-gex-reply

Comment: Your previous question had useful debugging information, which has now been edited out... Your client reports that it is `openssh 7.7` the server says it's `openssh 7.6` ... there have been some [bug fixes](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.7) which may lead to some connection failures... particularly the downgrade from `SHA-256` to `SHA-1` .... and some `known_hosts` fixes.... it's possible that the server has an older configuration that's trying to use SHA1 ... or you simply need to delete the locally stored server's fingerprint information in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

Comment: @MichaelProkopec None of the solutions in https://serverfault.com/questions/210408/ssh-access-problem-debug1-expecting-ssh2-msg-kex-dh-gex-reply had any effect.

Comment: @RubberStamp I have tried from a client using ````openssh 7.6````. Connection fails with a reset.The  ````-vvv````  output shows more activity, but connection attempt does not appear at all in the server log (set to DEBUG3).  The keys in the known_hosts file have all been updated. Note that these connections all succeed when attempted within the LAN. The failure happens only when forwarding through the router.

Comment: Question, I know this might sound stupid but, by forwarding through the router you don't mean while your still all on the same lan, do you?

Comment: @MichaelProkopec  Hi thanks. Not a stupid question at all. but yes that is what I mean. But this forwarding was working up until about three weeks ago. And the forwarding works for other services on the same host -- and on other hosts as well. It is happening only with SSH and whichever host on the LAN is serving the SSH -- for SSH 7.7 and 7.6 hosts.

Comment: Did your Router update its own firmware since then? Say maybe to protect itself against dnsmasq spoofing? The router may think it is being attacked because the supposed foreign client has a local mac and has the same public ip as the router its self.

Comment: Just now I realized I never asked which OS's in the client's list were the working ones. This router is it a PC and what one is michigan?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86301/discussion-between-michael-prokopec-and-stephen-boston).

Comment: @MichaelProkopec   Yes there was a firmware update. It is an ISP-provided modem/router. I had mentioned that in earlier post on this issue but see I didn't mention that in this post. Bad. Sorry. ISP tech support couldn't help. Your idea is interesting and I would like to follow up in chat but I'll be away until tomorrow. I'll try you then. The router is a feature of the modem. OSs are all Ubuntu -- 18.04 and 18.10. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MichaelProkopec Well would the firmware update issue you mention affect all services within the LAN? It will forward to other services on LAN hosts. It's just the SSH that's a problem. Later...

Comment: No, not necessarily. Could you post/pastebin a copy of the sshd_config on the host and the ssh_config on the client?

Comment: Ah... So there is something special about SSH. Although I can access other services, I can't get SSH even through another port or from any LAN host. However I can get through the router when trying from a VPN client. So... I think that's that for that for now. But anyway, here are the files you asked for. Perhaps you see some way around it but it's looking like a router issue. Have to add one on I guess?  https://pastebin.com/u/eholiday